# Macro to find the word previously searched in find and replace

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

Word has removed the browse object in lower right-hand corner to search forward/back for the current search item. I tried to find it as a command to add as shortcut key, but came up empty, so I'm trying to write/assign a macro to a shortcut key to move backward (up) to find the current search word.

E.g., I search for Chelmsford, and my code below sends me backward(up) in the document to instances of Chelmsford. BUT, when I search for a different word, say Margate, the macro doesn't change Chelmsford to Margate so any reverse search is only for Chelmsford not MArgate, or Jane, or basin, whatever word I'm currently searching.

I've scoured the net for coding that will do a reverse search, I can't find a command in Word for a shortcut key, and all the vba code I've seen has been for searching for x and replacing it with Y

I'm thinking I need to do a dim coding, but am clueless as to how I'd write it to use with .Text = "" search for whatever the current search word/phrase is, i.e., changing the previous search "Chelmsford" to the new search "Margate."

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find

    .Text = "Chelmsford"  <--- I want this text to change whenever the word changes in the find box--->

    .Forward = False
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you just remove the `.Text` line completely? If you are using the navigation box, that assigns the value to this property - you do not need to assign it yourself in VBA.

Comment: Which version of Word is involved, here? On which OS?

Comment: This Word 2019 sorry I didn't clarify that

Comment: KDavis, If I remove the text property is does go backward, but that sets the direction value in the Find/Replace box to go backward (up), which means I have to open it and change that setting. Good suggestion though. Find Next is auto programmed by MSWord to the F3 key. I don't know WHY they removed the object feature at the bottom of the scroll bar or at least give us the option to let it show.

Comment: WOOT! KDavis,Tried a mod ver of your suggestion and post code that worked in next comment!!! Thanks!

Comment: This does work

  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = False
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
     .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
       
I have to tap F4 twice, but I can live with that. THANK  YOU!!

Answer (score 1):

Moving OP's answer [from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118296/macro-to-find-the-word-previously-searched-in-find-and-replace#comment100756916_57118296) to the answer field, as it worked for him.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting 
With Selection.Find 
    .Forward = False 
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk 
    .Format = True 
    .MatchCase = False 
    .MatchWholeWord = False 
    .MatchWildcards = False 
    .MatchSoundsLike = False 
    .MatchAllWordForms = False 
End With 
Selection.Find.Execute 
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting 
With Selection.Find 
    .Forward = True 
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    Format = True
End With
```